# Gson parse Json

Tags: android, json, kotlin, gson

How i can parse this json using GSON?

```
[
 [
   456239452,180279471,"fsdgdfgdfg","T",
   "M",244,0,0,"",0,82,"","[]","fgfdgdfg",10
 ],
 [
   456239451,180279471,"9wnntiu5vu9mBeDiBej4swfcztjOS4nJe",
   "R","s",253,0,0,"",0,82,"","[]","cf46","g",14
 ]
]
```

My code:

```
data class Data(val list: List<List<String>>)

Gson().fromJson(json, Data::class.java).let {
    it.list.forEach {
        it.forEach {
            println(it)
        }
    }
}
```

My stacktrace

> com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was BEGIN_ARRAY at line 1 column 2 path $
>           at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:224)
>           at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:888)
>           at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:853)
>           at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:802)
>           at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:774)
>           at dchistov.vkmusic.music.MusicFragment$initAudio$1.doResume(MusicFragment.kt:58)
>           at kotlin.coroutines.experimental.jvm.internal.CoroutineImpl.resume(CoroutineImpl.kt:54)
>           at kotlinx.coroutines.experimental.DispatchedTask$DefaultImpls.run(Dispatched.kt:161)
>           at kotlinx.coroutines.experimental.DispatchedContinuation.run(Dispatched.kt:25)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask$RunnableExecuteAction.exec(ForkJoinTask.java:1412)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:285)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1152)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.scan(ForkJoinPool.java:1990)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1938)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:157)
>        Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was BEGIN_ARRAY at line 1 column 2 path $
>           at com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader.beginObject(JsonReader.java:385)
>           at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:213)
>           at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:888) 
>           at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:853) 
>           at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:802) 
>           at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:774) 
>           at dchistov.vkmusic.music.MusicFragment$initAudio$1.doResume(MusicFragment.kt:58) 
>           at kotlin.coroutines.experimental.jvm.internal.CoroutineImpl.resume(CoroutineImpl.kt:54) 
>           at kotlinx.coroutines.experimental.DispatchedTask$DefaultImpls.run(Dispatched.kt:161) 
>           at kotlinx.coroutines.experimental.DispatchedContinuation.run(Dispatched.kt:25) 
>           at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask$RunnableExecuteAction.exec(ForkJoinTask.java:1412) 
>           at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:285) 
>           at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1152) 
>           at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.scan(ForkJoinPool.java:1990) 
>           at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1938) 
>           at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:157)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the only thing you can do — it to parse it as `List<List<Any>>` and then access elements by indices.

To achieve this you should do something like

```
import java.lang.reflect.Type
import com.google.gson.reflect.TypeToken

Type listType = object: TypeToken<List<List<Any>>>(){}.type
List<List<Any>> list = Gson().fromJson(jsonArray, listType)
```